# Spring security oauth for Azure AD

Tags: azure, spring-security, azure-active-directory, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I need to add implementation to authenticate using Azure AD. Only helpful articles I have been able to trace is https://github.com/AzureCAT-GSI/DevCamp/tree/master/HOL/java/03-azuread-office365

But my web application doesn't uses Spring Boot as described in article above.
All the sample context xmls I have found describe how to confgiure webapp as authorization server.

What are the relevant configurations to be done in spring security xml to make it authenticate using azure ad?

Below is my xml with incorrect settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd
    ">
    <sec:http pattern="/" security="none"/>
    <!--<sec:http pattern="/login" security="none"/>-->
    <sec:http pattern="/resources/assets/**" security="none"/>
    <sec:http pattern="/resources/bootstrap/**" security="none"/>
    <sec:http pattern="/resources/config/**" security="none"/>
    <sec:http pattern="/resources/css/**" security="none"/>
    <!-- HTTP Root Access configuration -->
    <sec:http pattern="/rest/**" create-session="never" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
              entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
        <sec:anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
        <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthWebExpressionHandler"/>
    </sec:http>

    <!-- OAuth2 Authentication Entry Point -->
    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="conference"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler"/>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter">
                    <property name="expressionHandler" ref="oauthWebExpressionHandler"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!--<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler"/>-->
    <bean id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.expression.OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
    <!-- OAuth2 Token Generation Services -->
    <sec:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
              authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
        <sec:anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
        <sec:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
    </sec:http>

    <bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="300000"/>
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore"/>

    <bean id="approvalStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenApprovalStore">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userApprovalHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.ApprovalStoreUserApprovalHandler">
        <property name="approvalStore" ref="approvalStore"/>
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
        <property name="requestFactory">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
                <constructor-arg index="0" ref="clientDetails"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- OAuth2 Authorization Server -->
    <oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
                                user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
        <oauth:authorization-code/>
        <oauth:implicit/>
        <oauth:refresh-token/>
        <oauth:client-credentials/>
        <oauth:password/>
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <!-- OAuth2 Protected Resources Server -->
    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="conference" token-services-ref="tokenServices"/>

    <!-- OAuth2 Client Configuration -->
    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="conference/client"/>
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- OAuth2 Client's Authentication Manager -->
    <sec:authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService"/>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <!-- File based client details access -->
    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
        <!-- Web Application clients -->
        <oauth:client client-id="7c7ecd48-a83e-453c-b0f8-658edf4d1519"
                      secret=""
                      redirect-uri="http://localhost:8080/auth/openid/return"
                      authorities="APP"
                      authorized-grant-types="authorization_code"
                      resource-ids="conference"
                      scope="read,write,trust"/>
    </oauth:client-details-service>
    <oauth:resource client-id="7c7ecd48-a83e-453c-b0f8-658edf4d1519" authentication-scheme="header"
                    client-secret="" user-authorization-uri="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"
                    token-name="access_token" client-authentication-scheme="form" pre-established-redirect-uri="http://localhost:8080/auth/openid/return"
                    scope="openid,profile,User.Read, Mail.Send"
                    access-token-uri="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token"/>

    <sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
        <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler"/>
    </sec:global-method-security>

    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: All of your Azure AD configurations look correct.  I have a small app I built using Spring MVC w/ an open source library to plug into the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint (like you're doing above) [here](https://github.com/danieldobalian/AADv2JavaMVC). For general help with Azure AD, checkout the [dev guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview).  Can you expand on the error you're getting or specific question?

Comment: Hi, I get the error authorize_uri cannot be used with client_credentials grant type. I have tried commenting authorize server configuration as well, because as per my understanding so far, Azure AD would be the authorize server right? And thanks I will look into the sample application as well

Comment: I'm facing the same problem configuring an xml file for Azure AD integration. I wonder if there was a solution.

@Curiousreed Did you solve it? Does anyone have any reference of Azure AD integration with spring xml configuration?